# How to draw outside of pgfplots axis

Tags: pgfplots

How can I draw outside a pgfplots axis (without changing the axis). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,domain=-3:3]
\addplot {x^2};
\fill[red] (2,0) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (4,0) circle (2pt); %% How to show also this point without changing the axis
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the option `clip=false` to the `axis` environment. Note that the bounding box will be larger then in general.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works.

Comment: For more options (I like `clip mode=individual` see https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-bb-clip#sec-4.20.2

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to move the `\fill` outside the axis environment by creating named coordinates inside.  In this case it serves no advamtage, but it could be useful if you needed to use the clip or to prevent the circles from turning into ellipses.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,domain=-3:3]
\addplot {x^2};
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\end{axis}
\fill[red] (A) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (B) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]